# Using reference column with LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `SELECT` query with sub queries that are aliased as `nativePhraseString` and `foreignPhraseString`. I would like to use the aliases to compare with a search string.

```sql
SELECT item.itemID, item.groupID, item.itemType,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string SEPARATOR " ") FROM phrase, phrase_word, word, item AS subItem 
WHERE word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID 
AND phrase_word.phraseID=phrase.phraseID 
AND phrase.phraseID= subItem.nativePhraseID
AND subItem.itemID=item.itemID
ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex) AS nativePhraseString,

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string SEPARATOR " ") FROM phrase, phrase_word, word, item AS subItem 
WHERE word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID 
AND phrase_word.phraseID=phrase.phraseID 
AND phrase.phraseID= subItem.foreignPhraseID
AND subItem.itemID=item.itemID
ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex) AS foreignPhraseString

FROM item
WHERE item.groupID=:groupID
AND nativePhraseString LIKE :search
OR foreignPhraseString LIKE :search;
```

However, both `nativePhraseString` and `foreignPhraseString` are not recognised. How can I use them in the `LIKE` clauses?

BTW I'm using PDO to perform this query. The rest of the query is tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT item.itemID, item.groupID, item.itemType,

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string SEPARATOR " ") 
     FROM phrase, phrase_word, word, item AS subItem 
    WHERE word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID 
    AND phrase_word.phraseID=phrase.phraseID 
    AND phrase.phraseID= subItem.nativePhraseID
    AND subItem.itemID=item.itemID
    ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex) AS nativePhraseString,

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string SEPARATOR " ") FROM phrase, 
                   phrase_word, word, item AS subItem 
    WHERE word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID 
    AND phrase_word.phraseID=phrase.phraseID 
    AND phrase.phraseID= subItem.foreignPhraseID
    AND subItem.itemID=item.itemID
    ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex) AS foreignPhraseString

    FROM item
) xx
    WHERE xx.groupID=:groupID
    AND (xx.nativePhraseString LIKE :search
         OR xx.foreignPhraseString LIKE :search);
```

I added the extra parenthesis in the WHERE clause to make sure your order of operations is maintained.